# Even though there is no duplicate entry php my admin shows duplicate entry error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to import well worked database to my phpmyadmin, though there is no duplicate entry for primary key. Since I have made auto increment for primary key, there is no chance for duplicate entry for it.I am using mysql 5.6.11 version.

Comment: But, the duplicate may violate another unique constraint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may be to reasons for that

1)**let there are two tables in other table the first one table primary key is using as foreign key when you are importing the data the insert statements must be in order so that the table which primary key is using in another table must be insert data first**

2)truncate the table and try import again if the same error occur then the first step follow that

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution but I think it may give you the solution if your database and the data is not too large. Separate your sql file into two pieces one for creating database ,table and relation and another for inserting data managing according to the foreign key. Once I have solved by this way this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not import .sql sql script simply, import create table script first then insert script later, as mentioned above truncanting table first then import script with the correct order if you occured at last 1 conflict duplicate entry problem, try truncanting your table again to fix the problem